# Python - How to access variable data that was set by methods

Tags: python, django

I am taking a Django course on Udemy and have decided to add on to what I've learned by changing the layout of a form with an If statement.

Basically, I want to see if the BooleanField for the variable for_you is set to true (or if the check box in the GUI is checked), but I am having trouble figuring out how to access if the boolean field is set to false. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
for_you = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Is this purchase for you? If so, check this box.")
if for_you:
```

Comment: Be explicit. `if for_you == True` or `if for_you == False`. Of course, if you want to keep the coding style that you have: `if for_you:` or `if not for_you`

Comment: @Zizouz212 The latter is simpler, and just as clear if a more sensible variable name is chosen, e.g. `if is_for_you:`.

Comment: @figs The former though, has the advantage of being more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell us a bit more about the context where you're trying to access `for_you`.

I'm not sure if this will be helpful for you, but here's how to access `for_you` depending on where you are in relation to the `SignUp` class.

Inside a method of SignUp:

```
class SignUp(models.Model):

    def my_method(self):
        if self.for_you:
            # do stuff
```

Outside SignUp:

```
my_sign_up = SignUp()
if my_sign_up.for_you:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I really don't know how to ask the question because my lingo isn't up to par (and thus I don't know how to look for the question despite my efforts). the for_you variable is set by an object method. I need a way of checking if the object method is true. Simply checking if for_you == True or not does not produce the desired results. I'm not sure if it makes any sense, but I'm trying ;p

Comment: Where are you checking the `if for_you == True`; inside the model declaration, or outside the model declaration?

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way of checking if a boolean is `False` is using `not`:

```
if not for_you:
    print 'for_you is False!'
```

Comment: Strings are quotations!

Comment: @Zizouz212 oops trying to format as code in my code block, thanks.